# How do I access an array element in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here's a representation of my array:

```
    $arr
    [0]
    [code]='a code'
    [number]='a number'
    [1]
    [code]='a code'
    [number]='a number'
    [2]
    [code]='a code'
    [number]='a number'
    [3]
    .
    .
```

I'm doing a foreach loop to get all the [code] values am stuck: I forgot how to do it. Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Could you please provide a proper representation of the array? Is it an array of arrays? Please post your loop as well. Do you have troubles accessing the array? Maybe [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) helps.

Comment: Please mention clearly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like :

```
foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo 'code: ' . $item['code'];
}
```

I hope it will help !

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast the array as an object of type stdClass

```
$obj = (object) $arr
```

That said however, your post title seems to imply you want an object, but the post body seems like you just want to access an array key.

In which case you can just use the following. But it depends what exactly you mean by 'get all of the [code] values.'

```
foreach( $arr as $inner_array ) {
    $codes[] = $inner_array['code']; // Collect them all into a single dimensional array?
    echo $inner_array['code']; // Output it here?
}
```

Comment: If you're going to go through all the trouble of making an array and populate that contain properties of some class you have, why not just instantiate an object from the class and assign values that way? It would cut out a few steps and would be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo 'code:'.$item['code'];
}
```

I hope this helps.