# How to echo the value of the two dimension array?

Tags: php

**print_r($getPrice)** result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 5
            [price_qty] => 2
            [price] => 100.0000

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 6
            [price_qty] => 5
            [price] => 90.0000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 7
            [price_qty] => 8
            [price] => 80.0000

        )

)
```

i want to loop out the value of   [price_qty] and [price], i am sorry, i am a newbie of php, i don't know how to use foreach to output them value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access an array element in a multidimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227604/how-do-i-access-an-array-element-in-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($getPrice as $price) {
     echo $price['price_qty'];
     echo $price['price'];
}
```

Or if you prefer a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0, $prices = sizeOf($getPrice); $i < $prices; ++$i) {
    echo $getPrice[$i]['price_qty'];
    echo $getPrice[$i]['price'];
}
```

There are other ways of looping through arrays as well, for instance: using `current()` and `next()`.

Answer (score 2):

just read documentation [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) command

```
foreach($getPrice as $price) {
  echo $price['price_qty'];
  ..
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach Loop .

```
foreach($getPrice as $price) {
     echo $price['price_qty'];
     echo $price['price'];
}
```